# Open PDF link from document library view in new tab

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to open pdf link in new tab from SharePoint 2010 document library views when I googled for this most of link saying to use

```
target='_blank'
```

inside javascript but while I tried this approach the pdf is opening in a new window but I wanted to open in a tab. How can I open in new tab? Is there something to use like target='newtab'?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to setting the target attribute to "_blank" you need to remove the "onclick" attribute.

This guy shows you how do it using jquery [in his blog post](http://stumblingthroughsharepoint.blogspot.com/2012/08/pdf-files-and-sharepoint-2010_14.html).  You could also accomplish this with vanilla JavaScript.